# Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

When trying to install `ez_setup.py` from Python, I get this error.

I ran it in my `cmd` with

```
python C:\ez_setup.py
```

but I got this nasty error:

[image: Error]

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:1 char:106
+ [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCac ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by just clicking on the file directly. I previously set up `.py` files to run with Python and when clicking on it, a `cmd` screen opened and successfully ran the script.